# assetic:dump not working well symfony

Tags: symfony, assets, dump, assetic

i have a problem with the assetic:dump command. Here is main main admin twig template: Basically all resources which are needed in the admin are stored in the CoreBundle:

Twig admin_base:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

{% block title -%}<title>Admin</title>{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/datatables.min.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/fine-uploader.min.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/font-awesome.min.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/jquery-ui.min.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css'
    '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/signin.css'
    %}

    <link href="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
{% block menu -%} {% endblock %}
{% block body -%} {% endblock %}
{% block javascripts -%}
{% javascripts
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/fine-uploader.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/datatables.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.html5.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js'
'@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/RowReorder-1.1.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js'

%}
<script src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
{% block readyjs -%}

{{ tinymce_init() }}
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function post_order ( ord, url)
    {
        $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: { elem: ord }
                })
                .done(function( msg ) {
                    //  alert( msg );
                });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

    var optionsDatatables = {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'csvHtml5'
        ]
    }
    if($('#dattab').hasClass('allow-order'))
    {
        //if we want more properties
        // optionsDatatables.rowReorder = {
        //selector: 'tr',
        //   update: true,
        //   dataSrc: '.ord-id'
        //  }
        optionsDatatables.rowReorder = true;
    }

    var table =    $('#dattab').DataTable(optionsDatatables);
    var order;
    if($('#dattab').hasClass('allow-order')) {
        $('#dattab').on('draw.dt', function () {
                var rows = table.rows().data();
                var ord = new Array();
                for (var i = 0, ien = rows.length; i < ien; i++) {
                    ord[i] = rows[i].DT_RowId;
                }
                order = ord;
                $('#save_sort').fadeIn();
        });
    }
    $('#save_sort').click(function(){
       post_order(order,$('#dattab').data('url'));
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });

$('.datec').datepicker();

});
   </script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

I install the assets and then  try to dump them.

[image]

I have looked in the cache so it is trying to locate it in the same bundle but with no css folder:

```
        <?php

    // CoreBundle:Components:edit_delete.html.twig
    return array (
      '53dc317' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
          1 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/bootstrap.min.css',
          2 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css',
          3 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/datatables.min.css',
          4 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/fine-uploader.min.css',
          5 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/font-awesome.min.css',
          6 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/jquery-ui.min.css',
          7 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css',
          8 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css',
          9 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css',
          10 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css',
          11 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/css/signin.css',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'output' => '_controller/css/53dc317.css',
          'name' => '53dc317',
          'debug' => NULL,
          'combine' => NULL,
          'vars' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'c985255' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
          1 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js',
          2 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/fine-uploader.min.js',
          3 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-ui.min.js',
          4 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/datatables.min.js',
          5 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js',
          6 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.html5.js',
          7 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/Buttons-1.1.0/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js',
          8 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.min.js',
          9 => '@CoreBundle/Resources/public/js/RowReorder-1.1.0/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'output' => '_controller/js/c985255.js',
          'name' => 'c985255',
          'debug' => NULL,
          'combine' => NULL,
          'vars' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
      ),
      '103aba8' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          0 => 'bundles/core/css/bootstrap.min.css',
          1 => 'bundles/core/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
          2 => 'bundles/core/datatables.min.css',
          3 => 'bundles/core/fine-uploader.min.css',
          4 => 'bundles/core/font-awesome.min.css',
          5 => 'bundles/core/jquery-ui.css',
          6 => 'bundles/core/jquery-ui.structure.min.css',
          7 => 'bundles/core/jquery-ui.theme.min.css',
          8 => 'bundles/core/main.css',
          9 => 'bundles/core/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css',
          10 => 'bundles/core/signin.css',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'output' => '_controller/css/103aba8.css',
          'name' => '103aba8',
          'debug' => NULL,
          'combine' => NULL,
          'vars' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

So it has it also in multiple files in the cache. I cannot understand what is going on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another Twig template that has `{% stylesheets ... %}` block. And in this block you have exactly this string: `bundles/core/bootstrap-theme.min.css`.

Try to find it with your IDE and repair it.

Comment: I have found it .... This was it i have made a copy of one twig and forget that it is there.... Thank you very munch!